# Save one attribute for a row in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

There are like 5 ways to save a new value for an attribute in ActiveRecord.  Unfortunately I could only get one way to work and I am not sure it is the most efficient way:

```
review = Review.find(id)
review.status = 'ok'
review.save!
```

I started with the update method, but for some strange reason that deleted my review row

```
review = Review.update(id, :status => 'ok)
review.save!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to save a new value for an attribute is to simply do:

```
Review.update_attribute(id, :status => 'ok')
```

There is no need to call the save method after this because ActiveRecord automatically saves the value with the `update_attribute` method.

Now, keep in mind that this will only work if the change will only work if it passes the validations set on the object.

Check out this link for more info:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

Comment: update has been deprecated. please check my answer for an updated version.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
review = Review.find_by_id(id)
review.update_column(:status, 'ok')
```

has you can see [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column).

Note: `ActiveRecord::Base:update` has been deprecated in Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`review.update_attributes(status: 'ok')`